# Segmentation fault in C when using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

1. When this code is run, it shows a segmentation fault. But when address(LessThan)countarray is changed into address<=countarray, it works. I just want it to print one less array but it doesnt let me.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()
   {
   int n,check,divisor,countarray,address;
   int pn[100];

   for (n=2;n<100;n++){
       for (divisor=2;divisor<n;divisor++){
           if ((n/divisor)*divisor==n)    //if (n is not a prime number) 
               check++;
       }
       if (check==0){                    //if its a prime number,
           pn[countarray]=n;
           countarray++;
       }

       check=0;

   }

   for (address=0;address<countarray;address++)
       printf("address for %d is %d and ",pn[address],address);


   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: `countarray` is left uninitialised. `check`  as well.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You use many variables before they are initialized. Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value that will seem random. What if, for example, `countarray` have such a value that is out of bounds of the `pn` array? Then `pn[countarray]=n` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no problem with condition `address<countarray`, you should initialize **check** & **countarray** variable.

```
int n,check=0,divisor,countarray=0,address;
```